# Insert first vs insert all

Tags: oracle

I was referring a oracle documentation  and was quite confusing to understand the difference between insert first and insert all

Please guide me with proper example

Thanks for valuable answers.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are referring to multi-table inserts. You can use a conditional clause there to insert in one or more tables based on a where-clause. 
When using FIRST, the first condition that is met will be executed and the rest will be ignored. 
When using ALL, every condition will be evaluated and executed when true.

INSERT FIRST
WHEN (sal >= 5000) THEN
INTO rich (id, name, sal) VALUES (empno, ename, sal)
WHEN (sal >= 200) THEN
INTO medium  (id, name, sal) VALUES (empno, ename, sal)
WHEN (sal > 0 ) THEN
INTO poor  (id, name, sal) VALUES (empno, ename, sal)
SELECT * 
FROM emp;

INSERT ALL
WHEN (sal >= 5000) THEN
INTO rich (id, name, sal) VALUES (empno, ename, sal)
WHEN (sal >= 200) THEN
INTO medium  (id, name, sal) VALUES (empno, ename, sal)
WHEN (sal > 0 ) THEN
INTO poor  (id, name, sal) VALUES (empno, ename, sal)
SELECT * 
FROM emp;

if sal = 5000, there will be one insert into "rich" in the first statement (insert  first), and 3 inserts (in rich, medium and poor) in the last statement.

Comment: SQL> insert first 2 when salary>15000 then into rich values(id,name,sal) 3 when salary>10000 then into medium values(id, name, sal) 4 when salary>5000 then into poor values(id, name, sal) 5 select employee_id id, substr(last_name,1,10) name, salary sal from employees 6 / when salary>5000 then into poor values(id, name, sal) * ERROR at line 4: ORA-00904: "SALARY": invalid identifier 


Not catching the cause of error... suggestions

Comment: I hope you noticed it was a typo in the statement. I corrected it. Some basic knowledge of sql is required before trying constructs like these.